# Moving between view controllers using toolbar

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, navigation, toolbar

This is a beginner question
I want to move to the next view controller (OptionsView) when the button in the toolbar tapped, how can I do it?

```
var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Profile")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    
                    Button {
                        OptionsView()
                    } label: {
                        Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
}
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `isActive` property of a `NavigationLink` to programmatically activate the link. The `NavigationLink` can use `EmptyView` as it's label so that it's hidden, since you only need it to be activated via the `Button`.

Then, inside of your `Button`'s action, instead of trying to insert the view (which should always be in the view hierarchy -- not inside an action), you can set the the `@State` variable to activate.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var optionsActive = false
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text("Hello, World!")
                NavigationLink(isActive: $optionsActive) {
                    OptionsView()
                } label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Profile")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        optionsActive = true
                    } label: {
                        Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```